# Why does my IF statement not work on python?

Tags: python

```
import random
circlediameter = random.randint(1,99)
pi = 3.142
print("The circle diameter is",circlediameter,"   Find the area")

#find 4 possible answers
circleanswer1 = circlediameter/pi
circleanswer2 = circlediameter*pi
circleanswer3 = circlediameter+pi
circleanswer4 = circlediameter

#makes sure all numbers are integers
circleanswer1 = int(circleanswer1) 
circleanswer2 = int(circleanswer2)
circleanswer3 = int(circleanswer3)
circleanswer4 = int(circleanswer4)

answerlist = [circleanswer1 , circleanswer2 , circleanswer3 , circleanswer4]

#shuffles the list
random.shuffle(answerlist) 




#answer 2 is always the right answer
print("Four options are:    ", answerlist)


#user enters a number
useranswercircle = input("Please choose an answer:   ")
int(useranswercircle)


str(useranswercircle)
str(circleanswer2)

if useranswercircle == circleanswer2:
print("EEE")
```

I am comparing two integers, why is my IF statement not working when i 
compare two numbers. I have converted the two variables into integers, and it still isn't comparing successfully

Comment: `str(useranswercircle)` does *not* convert `useranswercircle` to a string: it produces an equivalent string. So you should write `useranswercircle = str(useranswercircle)`.

Comment: `int(useranswercircle)` - same ^

Comment: Last line should be indented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this cast:

```
import random
circlediameter = random.randint(1,99)
pi = 3.142
print("The circle diameter is",circlediameter,"   Find the area")

#find 4 possible answers
circleanswer1 = circlediameter/pi
circleanswer2 = circlediameter*pi
circleanswer3 = circlediameter+pi
circleanswer4 = circlediameter

#makes sure all numbers are integers
circleanswer1 = int(circleanswer1) 
circleanswer2 = int(circleanswer2)
circleanswer3 = int(circleanswer3)
circleanswer4 = int(circleanswer4)

answerlist = [circleanswer1 , circleanswer2 , circleanswer3 , circleanswer4]

#shuffles the list
random.shuffle(answerlist) 


#answer 2 is always the right answer
print("Four options are:    ", answerlist)


#user enters a number
useranswercircle = input("Please choose an answer:   ")

# EDIT:
# HERE IS THE TRICK
useranswercircle = int(useranswercircle)

if useranswercircle == circleanswer2:
    print("EEE")
```

Comment: The trick is into cast `useranswercircle` to int so it can be compared to `circleanswer2`

Comment: What do you mean by rev?

Comment: @narn yep you right, it's a problem with my tab settings

Comment: but does this mean i have to refer to 'useranswercircle' as 'int(useranswercircle)' for the rest of my code?

Comment: You are comaring an integer with a string. So the solutions is that either you cast the integer into a string or the other way around, so that they are comparable. Anyway you could also assign the integer value to the variable like I did in my edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the print:

```
if useranswercircle == circleanswer2:
    print("EEE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this -

```
if str(useranswercircle) == str(circleanswer2):
    print("EEE")
```

And remove these two statements -

```
str(useranswercircle)
str(circleanswer2)
```